# Four cycle engine with oil in gas. What should I do besides new spark plug?

Tags: honda, fuel-system, smoke, small-engine

Honda GC160  5.0 emits thick blue smoke. I used it several days when it came to a stop. Filled the tank with fresh (no mix) gas & it would not start. Bought & changed the old spark plug. After several removal & cleaning carbon off the plug, it finally kept running. Within 2 minutes there was smoke & I shut it off. (Power Washer). What is happening?

Comment: Have you checked the oil in the engine? Is it overfull?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!